# checking which UITextField is triggering textFieldShouldBeginEditing call

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

What's the best way to determine which `UITextField` triggers the method `-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` (or any of the other UITextFieldDelegate methods)?  I've seen code like this before:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (textField == textFieldCode) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

but this only works if I have `textFieldCode` as an ivar in my class, and in this case I'm just initializing a couple of `UITextField`s and putting them in a table, so I don't have references to them in the class.

I was thinking that I could use the [hash function](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/hash) and store the hashes for each textField somewhere in the class, and then compare `textField`'s hash to the desired hash in the method call, but that seems like kind of a hack.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do exactly? Depending on how you determine which text field should be allowed to edit, you could store the currently-allowed one in the class as, say, `currentTextField` and compare against that. More info would help :)

Comment: If you're considering storing hashes for the textField, why not store an array of pointers to the actual UITextFields? Doesn't seem like any extra work. Run Loops's solution is also good.

Comment: I want to have more than one text field editable at the same time, so I can't necessarily set `currentTextField` to whichever one it's going to be.  That's an interesting approach though; thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only have a couple of fields, you can assign unique numbers to the tag properties of each textfield to enable identification.

Comment: perfect, that's just what I needed.  also, tip for future SOers: add enum field to header file to make this more robust.

Comment: If your code gets too messy you can also factor out your code to separate helper objects that implement the textFieldDelegate protocol. One helper object for each field that the controller creates and assigns as the delegate. You can use notifications to update the controller with changes

Answer (score 0):

You can have an iVar of NSArray that will contain all the text fields.
Then just enumerate through it to find out which text field sent the message